# VHDL: Simulating Delay for ISE UNISIM components

Tags: vhdl, simulation, xilinx, ise, modelsim

I have extracted VHDL source of my design from Xilinx ISE.
It uses UNISIM library to model Look-Up Tables and Flip-Flops and other components. 
When I simulate my VHDL design (a combinational circuit) using ModelSIM, there are no delays displayed in simulated WaveForms.
I want to know how can I add delay to elements of UNISIM library and then see its effect on MODELSIM simulation?

Comment: There are three types of simulation: (a) behavioral simulation, (b) post map simulation and (c) post place&route simulation. Depending on the type, the tools use different libraries and delay models. Which type do you use?

Comment: I guess I have run behavioral simulation, however how can I run post map simulation in ModelSIM for Xilinx/UNISIM components?

Answer (score 1):

Each synthesis step generates it's own simulation model. So start start place&route and select 'generate post par simulation model' afterwards. Now you can launch your selected simulator iSim or vSim from ISE.

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach the generated SDF file when invoking the simulator (On ModelSim : Start Simulation ... / SDF panel")

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Delay_Format

This file looks like EDIF netlists or LISP code (full of parentheses), its purpose is to tag each primitive with delay parameters.

Answer (score 0):

The right way to do simulation considering components delay in ISE is to:

1. Compile `simprim` and `XilinxCoreLib`  using `compxlib` command
2. Do post-route simulation e.g. (anything other than behavioral simulation have built-in delays involved)